# submit a form on 'enter' key press

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I want to submit the form value in 'enter' key.I have a button search now to submit the value value.but I want to do it without search button on enter key press.

```
  html
    <input class="stxt" type="text" name="searchtxt"><a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
   <button name="search" class="search">Search</button></p>

  php
     if(isset($_REQUEST['search']))
       {
         $search=$_REQUEST['searchtxt'];
         some code here
       }
```

Comment: I want to trigger php  code not js.

Comment: If you have a form and a button/input with the type of submit, it will automatically click the submit button on enter when an input in the form is focused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code it will work.. I have coded without button only.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    echo $search = $_POST['search'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    document.onkeydown=function(evt){
        var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
        if(keyCode == 13)
        {
            //your function call here
            document.test.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="test" action="#" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I use this to certain button if I have multiple forms in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to trigger php code on every key press in which case good solution will be using AJAX.

```
 $( "#target" ).keypress(function(e) {
     $.ajax({
            url: "logic.php",
            type: post,
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {
                //Process data received from server.
            }
          });
 });
```

On each key press all form data will be serialized and send over to server where you can perform your logic.

Answer (score 0):

The button should be submitting on `Enter`, if it's not, there's something in the HTML that you have not provided. You have tagged the question with JQuery but have not provided any code, so I can only assume that you are submitting the form through only PHP.

Take a look at the [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) documentation. There are two paragraphs there that are relevant to your situation.

> **form** HTML5
>       The form element that the button is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be the id attribute of a
>    element in the same document. If this attribute is not
>   specified, the  element must be a descendant of a form
>   element. This attribute enables you to place  elements
>   anywhere within a document, not just as descendants of their 
>   elements.

This means that for the button to submit the form, it must be inside the `form` tags. If it is not, you need to specify the form id like this.

```
<button form="form_id">
```

The second relevant piece of information.

> **type**
>    The type of the button. Possible values are:
>    **submit:** The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is
>   dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
>    **reset:** The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
>    **button:** The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when
>   the events occur.

Since `type` defaults to `submit`, it means that the form will submit with the `Enter` key.